# redis and nodejs async needs to run twice

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read content of a key in redis using node redis module. 
it works but it's required to run twice to get redis updates please check the code below

```
client.lrange('resque:queue:default',0, -1, function(error, replies){


            replies.forEach(function(item){
                var parsed = JSON.parse(item);


                result.push({
                    'name' : parsed.args[0].name , 
                    'mobno' : parsed.args[0].mobno, 
                    'email' : parsed.args[0].email
                })
            })

        });

        res.json(result);
```

first run : return empty array []
second run : get the correct data with updates 
I need to refresh the application to get the recent updates.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `res.json(result);` to at the end of your `lrange()` callback:

```
client.lrange('resque:queue:default',0, -1, function(error, replies){
  replies.forEach(function(item){
    var parsed = JSON.parse(item);

    result.push({
      'name' : parsed.args[0].name , 
      'mobno' : parsed.args[0].mobno, 
      'email' : parsed.args[0].email
    })
  })

  res.json(result);
});
```

Typically whenever you see something that takes a callback, it's asynchronous, so that means the function call will return right away before anything has been done. That is why `result` is empty the first time, the `lrange()` callback hasn't been executed at that point yet.